# Problem deploying a webpart in multi servers enviornement

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

[image]I have a webpart which is deployed correctly in test environment but it fails to deploy when we deploy it in production environment 2013.

structure is as follows

Web front end server 1 load balanced

web front end server 2 load balanced

Application server1
application server2

I am using Application server 1 to deploy the webpart . it deploys fine on that particular server when i see in farm solutions but it fails for other 3 saying web.config is invalid. where i am going wrong?

Comment: but did it go through even after the invalid web.config error? can you check the from central admin and manage farm solutions? also could you please update the exact error u are getting?

Comment: actualy it shows error in farm solution. but when i open for status it shows error in 3 other servers